# Scan S3 for most recent file

Tags: java, amazon-s3

We've got some data to store on S3 and want to be able to fetch the most recently uploaded file.

Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

We're currently using the [jets3t](http://www.jets3t.org/api/org/jets3t/service/model/S3Object.html) library.

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring Boot:

```
@Service
public class AWSS3Service {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(AWSS3Service.class);

@Autowired
private AmazonS3 amazonS3;

@Value("${aws.s3.bucket}")
private String bucketName;

@Value("${aws.s3.folder.download}")
private String foldernameDownload;

public byte[] downloadFile(final String typeName) {
    
    byte[] content = null;
    LOGGER.info("Downloading most recent file from {}",  typeName);
    
    ObjectListing objects = amazonS3.listObjects(bucketName,foldernameDownload+"/"+ typeName+"/");
    
    Date tempDate = null;
    S3ObjectSummary recentObj = null;
    
    List<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummaries = objects.getObjectSummaries();
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectSummaries) {
        
        if (objectSummary.getSize()<=0)
            continue;
        
        Date modifiedDate = objectSummary.getLastModified();
        
        if(tempDate == null || modifiedDate.compareTo(tempDate) > 0) {
            tempDate = modifiedDate;
            recentObj = objectSummary;
        } 
    }
    
    String obKey ="";
    if(recentObj != null)
        obKey = recentObj.getKey();
    else
        return content;//no files found
    
    S3Object s3Object = amazonS3.getObject(bucketName,obKey);
    S3ObjectInputStream stream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
    try {
        content = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
        LOGGER.info("File downloaded successfully.");
        s3Object.close();
    } catch(final IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("IO Error Message= {}", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return content;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help..

```
S3Service s3Service = new S3Service(providerCredentials);

Date tempDate = null;
S3Object recentObj = null;

for(S3Object object : s3Service.listObjects("bucketName")) {
    modifiedDate =(Date)object.getMetadata(BaseStorageItem.METADATA_HEADER_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE); 
    if(tempDate == null) {
        tempDate = modifiedDate;
    } else {
        if(modifiedDate.compareTo(tempDate) < 0) {
             tempDate = modifiedDate;
             recentObj = object;
    }
    }
 }
```

I have not tested this code. Hope this helps..

Comment: This error appears "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"